# Upsize (explode) CGImageRef like iPhone simulator on iPad. 1px to 2px

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I would like to upsize (explode) the image by duplicating pixels.

1 px -> 2px

Knowing how to read individal pixels (RGBA):

```
CFDataRef m_DataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(myImage));  
UInt8 * m_PixelBuf = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(m_DataRef); 

int length = CFDataGetLength(m_DataRef); 

for (int i=0; i<length; i+=4){

    int r = i;
    int g = i+1;
    int b = i+2;
    int a = i+3;   
}
```

How do I go about upsizing the image. I tried copying pixels in a linear fashion but I ended up with an image of two images side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a CGBitmapContext at the destination size then draw the image to it.

Comment: Thanks! I alway tend to go the harder way!

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a very easy-to-use library for iOS called [ANImageBitmapRep](https://github.com/unixpickle/ANImageBitmapRep).  The `ANImageBitmapRep` class allows you to easily scale images in a number of different ways, including the most basic:

```
UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
ANImageBitmapRep * irep = [ANImageBitmapRep imageBitmapRepWithImage:myImage];
[irep setSize:BMPointMake(width, height)];
UIImage * scaled = [irep image];
```

This will achieve what you are looking to do without having to deal with tons of bitmap contexts and CoreGraphics.  I will also note that every `ANImageBitmapRep` is backed by a `CGContextRef`, which can be easily retrieved using the `context` method.  If you manually change the context, just run `[myBitmap setNeedsUpdate:YES]`.

You can also use the `setSizeFittingFrame:` and `setSizeFillingFrame:` methods for scaling that will never take the image out of proportion.